# Unable to catch event in NestJs

Tags: event-handling, nestjs

I'm doing some test with NestJs events.
Here is the code (very basic)

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OnEvent, EventEmitter2 } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';

@Controller('messages')
export class MessagesController {
  constructor(private eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) {}

  @Post()
  async postMessage(@Body() message: any) {
    this.eventEmitter.emit('custom.event', { data: message });
  }

  @OnEvent('custom.event', { async: true })
  handleEvent(payload: any) {
    console.log(payload);
  }
}
```

I imported module in AppModule like that

```
EventEmitterModule.forRoot({
      wildcard: true,
      delimiter: '.',
    }),
```

When I perform POST request, event is not catch by the listener. What did I missed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/event-emitter/blob/1a6bc4defde70d0a6dba38a574f936e2e6eeb33b/lib/event-subscribers.loader.ts#L30) it appears that `Controllers` are not scanned when connecting subscribers.

Only `Providers` are scanned which means you will need to create a dedicated Injectable Service to have your `@OnEvent` method decorated

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes in AppModule

Comment: @barden Check my updated answer it should help get you unblocked

Comment: Thanks, I just move the function on MessageService and it work. Thanks for your help !